# Machine level environment variable not available after setting in Powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, powershell-4.0

The following code does not return "Y" as expected. Only in the next session (another new window) it works? I would expect it to be available immediately?

```
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("X", "Y", "Machine")
    Write-Host $env:X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do this since the process gets env vars on start, not while running (i.e. you would have to restart shell for this to work your way):

```
 [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("X", "Y", "Machine")
 $Env:X = "Y"
```

There is also a way to broadcast this to other windows using [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx)

> To effect a change in the environment variables for the system or the
>   user, broadcast this message with lParam set to the string
>   "Environment".)

```
# Notify system of change via WM_SETTINGCHANGE
    if (! ("Win32.NativeMethods" -as [Type]))
    {
        Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name NativeMethods -MemberDefinition @"
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout( IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, string lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
"@
    }

    $HWND_BROADCAST = [IntPtr] 0xffff; $WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a; $result = [UIntPtr]::Zero
    [Win32.Nativemethods]::SendMessageTimeout($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE, [UIntPtr]::Zero, "Environment", 2, 5000, [ref] $result) | out-null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a process loads the environment variables only once (at start). But you can change it using:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("X", "Y", "Process") # for the current session
```

Note: You probably want to set both:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("X", "Y", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("X", "Y", "Process")
```